# How can I attach a LaTeX marker to an arbitrary place in text?

Tags: latex

Is it possible to attach a marker to just a place in text, not to section, sub-section, etc.?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\begin{document}
Alex (see~\ref{alex}) is a boy, 
Jessica (see~\ref{jessica}) is a girl.
[...]
\label{alex}\ref{alex}: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
\label{jessica}\ref{jessica}: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
\end{document}
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Alex (see 1) is a boy, 
Jessica (see 2) is a girl.
[...]
1: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
2: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Did you know that there was a latex stackoverflow clone? I just can't seem to find the link. :/

Comment: My answer was "look for answer elsewhere, since ye won't find one here". I was spot on the money. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
\newcounter{foo}
Alex (see~\ref{alex}) is a boy, 
Jessica (see~\ref{jessica}) is a girl.
[...]
\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo\label{alex}: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo\label{jessica}: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
```

Posted by Will at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/how-to-set-a-marker-counter-label-to-an-arbitrary-piece-of-text

Comment: Ah, `\refstepcounter` -- that's it! That's what sets `\@currentlabel`.  The only thing you could potentially add would be something like `\newcommand\refitem{\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `label`, consider the following (from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing));

- `\label{marker}` You give the object you want to reference a marker, you can see it like a name.
- `\ref{marker}` You can reference the object you have marked before. This prints the number that was assigned to the object.
- `\pageref{marker}` It will print the number of the page where the object is.

Normally, if you `ref`erence to a label, LaTeX prints out the section, subsection, etc. But if you want to specify the exact place in text, you can use `pageref`. So with `pageref` you can exactly print out the page number of the "marker".

This is - as far as i know - the most exact possibility to tell the reader where in text a "marker" was, i.e. it is - as far as i know - impossible to tell LaTeX to print the exact line number or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\label` anywhere, including in the body of the text, but the thing labelled will be (roughly) the 'current labellable thing', that is the last `\*section`, or the current equation or table.

If you want to label something else (what is it you're after?) then you'll have to roll your own (not trivial), and have something which, if I recall correctly, sets `\@currentlabel`.

**Edited**, to add:

```
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
Here is some text
\label{l1}
More text.
\newpage
Further text, on page 2
\label{l2}

This is section~\ref{l1} on page~\pageref{l1}.
And section~\ref{l2} on page~\pageref{l2}.
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the `\ref` refers to section 1, though the `\pageref` refers to pages 1 and 2 respectively.  In both cases, the 'thing being labelled' is the section, and the *text* that goes in the label, and which appears in the `\ref`, is the section number.

So if you want to refer to an 'arbitrary place in the text', you have to ask yourself 'what is the text that would be produced by the `\ref`?'

Comment: I want to label just a place in text, which is unique in my context.. How can I do it?

Comment: See my edit above.  It's still not clear what you're looking for.  Can you give an example – what would the cross-reference look like?  For example, after you've added a `\label{mylabel}` after a section, the text `see section~\ref{mylabel}` turns into _see section 1.2_ or something like that.

Comment: I've made changes to my questions, please see above